# Is it possible to get data from multiple collections at the same time from firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am storing the data from a quiz both after completion and after each question answered based on the email of the user taking the quiz.

Here I am storing the data after the submission:

```
const handleQuizSubmission = async (answers = userAnswers) => {
let totalScore = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  const question = questions[i];
  const userAnswerIndex = answers[i];
  const correctAnswerIndex = question.answer;

  if (userAnswerIndex === correctAnswerIndex) {
    totalScore += 1;
  }
}

const scorePercentage = (totalScore / questions.length) * 100;
const message = `Quiz submitted! Score: ${totalScore}/${questions.length} (${scorePercentage}%)`;
setShowDialog(true);
setDialogMessage(message);
setIsSubmitted(true);

const initialTimer = quizData.timer || 0;
const timeTaken = formatTime(initialTimer - timer);

try {
  const quizId = "iiLd3ZUp3EFYAfZxg1RS"; 
  const userRef = collection(db, `Results/${quizId}/${user.email}`);

  await setDoc(doc(userRef, 'results'), {
    score: totalScore,
    player: user.email,
    totalQuestions: questions.length,
    quizTitle: quizData.title,
    timeTaken: timeTaken,
    answers: questions.map((question, index) => ({
      id: question.id,
      question: question.question,
      answer: question.options[answers[index]],
    })),
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error storing quiz results:', error);
}
};
```

and here after each question:

```
  const handleAnswerSelect = async (index, correct) => {
    if (!isSubmitted) {
      setSelectedAnswerIndex(index);
      const updatedUserAnswers = [...userAnswers];
      updatedUserAnswers[currentQuestionIndex] = index;
      setUserAnswers(updatedUserAnswers);
      if (correct) {
        setScore(score + 1);
      }
      
      const quizId = "iiLd3ZUp3EFYAfZxg1RS";
      const questionId = questions[currentQuestionIndex].id;
      try {
        await setDoc(doc(db, `QuizResults/${quizId}/${user.email}/Answers`), {
          questionId: questionId,
          userId: user.email,
          question: currentQuestion.question,
          answer: currentQuestion.options[index],
          correct: correct,
          timeLeft: formatTime(timer),
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error storing user answer:', error);
      }
    }
  };
```

This is how my database structure looks like:

[image]

What I want is to get the data from multiple users at the same time and display it on my table:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import { Button, Container, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { TableContainer, Table, TableHead, TableBody, TableRow, TableCell } from '@mui/material';
import { db } from '../../FireBase/Firebase';
import { collection, doc, getDoc, onSnapshot } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { UserAuth } from '../../context/AuthContext';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    background: '#D4F1F4',
    minHeight: '100vh',
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  appContainer: {
    background: '#fff',
    borderRadius: 10,
    padding: 30,
  },
  button: {
    width: 20,
    height: 40,
    borderRadius: 0,
  },
}));

const QuizResults = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [quizData, setQuizData] = useState(null);
  const [quizResults, setQuizResults] = useState([]);
  const [quizAnswers, setQuizAnswers] = useState([]);
  const { user } = UserAuth()

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchQuizData = async () => {
      const quizId = "iiLd3ZUp3EFYAfZxg1RS";
      const quizRef = doc(db, 'Quizzes', quizId);
      const snapshot = await getDoc(quizRef);
      const quizData = snapshot.data();

      if (quizData) {
        setQuizData(quizData);
      }
    };
    fetchQuizData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const quizId = "iiLd3ZUp3EFYAfZxg1RS";
    const quizResultsRef = collection(db, `Results/${quizId}/${user.email}`);
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(quizResultsRef, (snapshot) => {
      const resultsData = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
      setQuizResults(resultsData);
    });
  
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [user.email]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const quizId = "iiLd3ZUp3EFYAfZxg1RS";
    const quizAnswerRef = collection(db, `QuizResults/${quizId}/${user.email}`);
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(quizAnswerRef, (snapshot) => {
      const answersData = {};
      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        const answer = doc.data();
        answersData[answer.questionId] = {
          answer: answer.answer,
          correct: answer.correct,
          timeLeft: answer.timeLeft,
        };
      });
      setQuizAnswers((prevAnswers) => ({ ...prevAnswers, ...answersData }));
    });
  
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [user.email]);

  const handleResetAnswers = () => {
    setQuizAnswers([]); 
    setQuizResults((prevResults) => [
      {
        ...prevResults[0],
        score: 0,
        timeTaken:'0:00'
      },
    ]);
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const savedAnswers = localStorage.getItem('quizAnswers');
    if (savedAnswers) {
      setQuizAnswers(JSON.parse(savedAnswers));
    } else {
      handleResetAnswers();
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('quizAnswers', JSON.stringify(quizAnswers));
  }, [quizAnswers]);
  

    return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Container className={classes.appContainer} maxWidth="lg">
        <div style={{ marginBottom: '3.3rem', marginTop: '1.5rem', textAlign: 'center' }}>
          <h2>{quizResults && quizResults[0]?.quizTitle}</h2>
        </div>
        <TableContainer>
          <Table>
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>User</TableCell>
                {quizResults &&
                  quizResults[0]?.answers &&
                  quizResults[0].answers.map((_, index) => (
                    <TableCell key={index}>{quizData.questions[index].question}</TableCell>
                  ))}
                <TableCell>Time taken</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Score</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>{user.email}</TableCell>
                {quizResults &&
                  quizResults[0]?.answers &&
                  quizResults[0].answers.map((_, index) => {
                    const questionId = `question_${index + 1}`;
                    const selectedAnswer = quizAnswers[questionId]?.answer;
                    const answerData = quizAnswers[questionId];
                    const isCorrectAnswer = answerData && answerData.correct;
                    const options = quizData.questions[index].options;

                    return (
                      <TableCell key={questionId}>
                        <div>
                          {options.map((option) => {
                            const isSelectedAnswer = selectedAnswer === option;
                            let backgroundColor = 'transparent';

                            if (isSelectedAnswer) {
                              backgroundColor = isCorrectAnswer ? '#88ff88' : '#ff8888';
                            }

                            return (
                              <Typography
                                key={option}
                                variant="body2"
                                style={{
                                  backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
                                }}
                              >
                                {isSelectedAnswer ? option : ''}
                              </Typography>
                            );
                          })}
                        </div>
                      </TableCell>
                    );
                  })}
                <TableCell>{quizResults && quizResults[0]?.timeTaken}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                  {quizResults && quizResults[0]?.score}/{quizResults && quizResults[0]?.totalQuestions}
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: '1rem' }}>
          <Button sx= {{marginTop: '2rem', marginBottom: '0.6rem',}}variant="contained" onClick={handleResetAnswers}>
            Reset Answers
          </Button>
        </div>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default QuizResults;
```

Can the data from each collection be taken at the same time for each user who is taking the quiz? If I try to modify the database reference I get this type of error:

> Error fetching quiz results: FirebaseError: Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but Results/iiLd3ZUp3EFYAfZxg1RS has 2.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to read data from multiple collection at once in Firestore is by [using a collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query). But that requires that all collections have the same name, which doesn't seem to be the case here.

I typically address this by having well-known (hard-codable) collection names, and in your scenario for example them storing the email address as a field in each document under that well-known collection name.